# 'Strange' behavior with nested ContinueWith statements

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have inherited a web service that uses asynchronous calls for various things, but I have run into an issue that I can't rightfully explain.

I have (basically) the following workflow.

```
public CustomObject Work()
{
    //synchronous work omitted
    ContinueWithMethod1();
    return retval;
}

public void ContinueWithMethod1()
{
     ContinueWithMethod2().ContinueWith(x=> 
     { 
         if(x.IsFaulted) { //log error } 
     });
}

public Task<CustValue> ContinueWithMethod2()
{
    <AzureDocumentDBLibrary>.UpsertDocumentAsync(value, value).ContinueWith(y =>
    {
       if(y.IsFaulted) throw y.Exception;
       //populate CustValue
       return retval;
    }
    );
}
```

The idea here is that the call to `ContinueWithMethod1()` inside of the `Work()` method is "fire and forget" so that execution passes to the `return retval;` statement immediately after calling `ContinueWithMethod1()`. If I put breakpoints on `ContinueWithMethod1()` and `ContinueWithMethod2()` the breakpoints are hit as I would expect and I don't see any errors generated in Visual Studio.  The problem is that my call to Azure doesn't upload anything.

Some additional points:

- If I execute this logic twice in a row the second call succeeds *every* time, but the first *always* fails.
- If I change `ContinueWithMethod1()` to match the code sample below, everything works fine on the first pass through.

Code sample follows

```
public async void ContinueWithMethod1()
{
     await ContinueWithMethod2();
}
```

The problem I think I have here is that depending on how long `ContinueWithMethod2()` my webrequest connection between the user and the server could time out.

Has anyone ever run into this problem with nested `ContineWith()` statements?  If so can you explain what is going on and maybe how to debug the sequence of events that result in my first call to Azure being lost?